# In llvm-hs, is linking required between known lists of Definition's, to have a valid Module, or can I just concatenate the lists?

Tags: haskell, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to make a compiler using LLVM Haskell bindings provided by `llvm-hs`.
I have not yet reached the point to actually use the bindings, I am trying to generate LLVM IR.
I have a bunch of functions, already defined, that I would like to have in each Module that I later create. I was wondering, can I use `execModuleBuilder` on each function, and concatenate the lists of definitions to be used to create a `Module`?

I thought about considering these functions a library and just linking them to each Module I create, but isn't concatenating the lists of `Definition`'s and throwing them in a Module pretty much the same thing? I guess as far as optimality goes, it is better to consider them a library.

My question still remains, since they are not external definitions, rather LLVM functions, and I could add more in the future, can I generally concatenate lists of `Definition`'s?

EDIT: I should mention that currently all of my objects have external linkage, which I think enables what I am trying to do.

Comment: What version of `llvm-hs` are you using? I don't see `execModuleBuilder` or `Definition` in [the index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-hs-9.0.1/docs/doc-index-All.html) for versions 7, 8, or 9 (I got lazy and didn't check any further back than that).

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned but did not clarify. `llvm-hs` provides the bindings, but I am not there yet. i am using `llvm-hs-pure` to create a haskell adt which is to be translated to llvm IR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModuleBuilderT` is a newtype wrapper around `StateT ModuleBuilderState`, and exposes the full state-ful API. So *in principle* a `ModuleBuilderT` action could do things that do not cleanly compose in the way you suggest (concatenating `[Definition]`s).

However, from my read of the code, all of the `ModuleBuilderT` actions exported from `LLVM.IRBuilder.Module` treat the state as an append-only log, not using the full stateful superpowers available to them. So if you only use actions available from that module, and don't define any of your own actions that do strange things with the `ModuleBuilderState`, then you should be good to go.

If there are actions available in other modules, they should be audited for calls to `liftModuleState` or `unModuleBuilderT` and for pattern matches on the `ModuleBuilderT` constructor. If they do none of those, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarifies things a little bit. Raises the question, what is the correct way to go about it? Have one Module for each function and link them with LLVM's linker?